# For the GOP primary, where can I see the list of complete rules of how each state allocates delegates, updated for 2024?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, republican-primary, rnc

For the 2016 GOP primary, *RealClear Politics* has a [nice table containing complete rules for each state](https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2016/president/republican_delegate_count.html) on how to count delegates.  But I cannot find a similarly complete rules in a table like that for the 2024 GOP primary.

The following websites have tables (one row per state) but the rules are not complete:

- [Ballotpedia](https://ballotpedia.org/Republican_delegate_rules,_2024)
- [FrontloadingHQ](https://www.frontloadinghq.com/p/2024-republican-delegate-allocation.html)
- [Election Central](https://www.uspresidentialelectionnews.com/2024-primary-schedule/)

In the above, I could *not* find these details:

- the minimum qualifying threshold to gain a delegate
- the % threshold where winner-take-all, even for states with proportionality rule
- whether the proportionality per congressional district or for the whole state
- etc.

Since 2016, there seems to be updates.  For example:

- by having a [threshold of 50% in California](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2023/07/30/trump-republican-delegates-primary/) where "winner-take-all" even though California is one of the [states needing to allocate proportionally since the primary is before March 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2024_Republican_Party_presidential_primaries#Delegates):

  > Under the new [July 2023] California GOP rules, any candidate who receives a majority of votes statewide — 50 percent plus 1 — will win all of the at-large and congressional district delegates, as well as the alternates.
- by having a [higher minimum threshold](https://nymag.com/intelligencer/2023/03/2024-delegate-rules-could-give-trump-and-or-desantis-a-boost.html) for a candidate to be assigned delegate:

  > Of the 26 states in 2020 that could have a qualifying threshold – those with some form of proportional rules – 18 of them set it to the maximum 20 percent. Just ten states of the 31 that could have a qualifying threshold had the maximum in 2016. The 20 percent maximum was by far the modal qualifying threshold for states in the 2020 cycle.

**Question**: Where can I find a table summarizing GOP Primary *complete* rules for **how each state allocates delegate** (including **state-specific rule details** such as minimum qualifying threshold, ceiling threshold to winner-take-all, what kind of proportionality used, etc), updated for 2024?  I'm primarily interested in the Presidential election.

Comment: When researching, I found [The Green Papers website](https://www.thegreenpapers.com/) which is very complete (see [here](https://www.thegreenpapers.com/P24/TX-R#0319) for Texas), even has the source text of the rules.  I think from these detailed rules, a table like [this 2016 table from *Real Clear Politics*](https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2016/president/republican_delegate_count.html) can be constructed.

Comment: It's probably not in any single place. Each state has their own party committees for each party. The rules for that state will be in that committee's policy documents.

Answer (score 3):

The Rules of the Republican Party which apply to the 2024 primary season can be found [here](https://prod-static.gop.com/media/Rules_Of_The_Republican_Party.pdf). It doesn't have a table. The original source explains it all in body text only.

Comment: While the document you cited is certainly very helpful, it only sets the ground rules (in pages 21-22) that each state can then customize.  For example, under Rule 16.c.3.i it says that "a state may establish by statewide vote or congressional district minimum threshold of the percentage of votes received by a candidate that must be reached, below which a candidate may receive no delegates, provided such threshold is no higher than twenty percent (20%)". What I'm looking for is **how each state customize the rules**, such as presented in the 2016 table by *RealClear Politics* linked in the OP.

Comment: OK. I misunderstood what you were asking.

Comment: My apologies, I should have been clearer; just updated the question accordingly.